# Check if a string contains special characters except period and question mark Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to find a way to use regex and match to see if a string contains a special character with the exception of a period or comma. I'm not very familiar with regex and about to bang my head on a wall. What is the regex to when I call

```
string.matches("??????");
```

will return a boolean based on whether string contains a special character other than a period or comma?

Comment: What are the special characters?

Comment: !@#$%^&*()_+-= and such. Anything that isn't a letter or a period or a comma really  --- and spaces are ok

Comment: Sorry I meant a period or a question mark, and numbers are not allowed

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can write:

```
string.matches("[a-zA-Z.? ]*")
```

That will evaluate to `true` if every character in the string is either a lowercase letter `a-z`, an uppercase letter `A-Z`, a period, a question mark, or a space. (And to `false` otherwise, of course.)